# Resources on the grammar of Maths?

Tags: soft-question, book-recommendation, online-resources

I recently came across a book called [How to think like a mathematician](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/6220915), which covers some of the general principles behind reading, writing, and understanding undergraduate level mathematics.

I would consider this book to be a walkthrough of mathematical grammar. Are there any others that take a similar approach?

Comment: $\mathscr{L} = \big\{c_i, v_j, f^{n_k}_k, R^{m_l}_l, \forall, \exists, \neg, \wedge, \square, \Diamond, \blacksquare,...\big\}$

Comment: @KevinS Please keep going 

Comment: If you take "mathematical grammer" to mean the syntax of a particular theory (algebra, analysis, etc. for undergrad), then instantiating the above comment should suffice as this is the "alphabet" for most statements. This is seen in Logic courses... see Enderton's book for reference.

Comment: Sorry this may not be a similar approach, I haven't read the hyperlink

Comment: Thankyou! Could you please provide me with a hyperlink to Enderton's book?

Comment: Just in case, someone looks for a German book in that genre:
A. Beutelspacher, *Das ist o.B.d.A. trivial!*. Afaik it has not been translated.

Comment: http://libgen.is/search.php?req=enderton+mathematical+introduction+to+logic&lg_topic=libgen&open=0&view=simple&res=25&phrase=1&column=def

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps "The Language of Mathematics: A Linguistic and Philosophical Investigation" by Mohan Ganesalingam? It focuses on how mathematicians actually use language in their writing from the perspective of a linguist.

Comment: I read the blurb of this book, and looked at some reviews on goodreads: https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/208737. One review stuck out to me. The reviewer said this book is like an overview of the ideas behind mathematics and doesn't focus on the how. What do you think of that? Is this book practical? Could it help me get a working understanding of the grammar of mathematics or is it more about the culture?

Comment: @Connor not the same book.  The review you reference is for a different book by Keith Devlin that happens to have the same title.

Comment: Ganesalingam's text doesn't seem to be intended as an introduction to mathematical language, rather an analysis.